# comparing list and returning new list

Tags: python, list, loops, nested

Hi so I'm trying to program my function that takes in a nested list, a number which select which row and then a specific number. So what its suppose to do is take in 3 parameter elevation_map which is a nested List, map_row which selects the row, and level which is a int. and it returns how many times the specific row is less than, equal to and greater than level.

So for now I created a loop which would go through the specific row of nested list and i'm trying to go through each number and see if its less than, equal to and greater than level which is the third parameter and return it

Example is  compare_elevations_within_row(THREE_BY_THREE, 1, 5), 
THREE_BY_THREE = [[1, 2, 1], [4, 6, 5], [7, 8, 9]]
and it returns [1,1,1]

```
def compare_elevations_within_row(elevation_map: List[List[int]], map_row: int,
                                  level: int) -> List[int]:
    """Return a new list containing the three counts: the number of
    elevations from row number map_row of elevation map elevation_map
    that are less than, equal to, and greater than elevation level.

    >>> compare_elevations_within_row(THREE_BY_THREE, 1, 5)
    [1, 1, 1]
    THREE_BY_THREE = [[1, 2, 1],
                  [4, 6, 5],
                  [7, 8, 9]]


    """
    num = elevation_map[map_row]
    count = []
    for index in num:
        if index < level:
            count[0] = count + 1
        elif index== level:
            count[1] = count + 1
        else:
            count[2] = count + 1
    return count
```

Comment: Can you explain better what this program does?

Comment: Can you add output you have and output you expect?

Comment: You initialized `count` to an empty list.  `count[0]` (and so on) *does not exist*, you cannot assign to it.  You have to use `.append()` (or `.extend()`) to increase the size of the list, although I'm not sure exactly what you should be appending as `count + 1` is not meaningful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems here. The first is that your count list is empty. So, when you try something like `count[0] = count + 1` you will encounter an `IndexError` since you are referring to an element that does not exist (the first element of the list in this case). Instead of `count = []` you probably want something like `count = [0, 0, 0]`.

The second problem is that when you increment the counter for `count[value]` you need to refer to that same list index on the right hand side also. Instead of `count[0] = count + 1` you will want `count[0] = count[0] + 1`, or if you want to be concise `count[0] += 1`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few small issues:

- `count` should be initialized with three zeros (A)
- when you increment the values at a given `count` index, you should base it off of the current value at that index (B)

Additionally, when you iterate over a list, you're iterating over the *values* of the list, not the indices as your variable names suggest.  (I changed `index` to `value` to make that clear.)

Consider:

```
def compare_elevations_within_row(elevation_map: List[List[int]], map_row: int,
                                  level: int) -> List[int]:
    """Return a new list containing the three counts: the number of
    elevations from row number map_row of elevation map elevation_map
    that are less than, equal to, and greater than elevation level.

    >>> compare_elevations_within_row(THREE_BY_THREE, 1, 5)
    [1, 1, 1]
    THREE_BY_THREE = [[1, 2, 1],
                  [4, 6, 5],
                  [7, 8, 9]]


    """
    count = [0] * 3             # (A)
    for value in elevation_map[map_row]:
        if value < level:
            count[0] += 1       # (B)
        elif value == level:
            count[1] += 1       # (B)
        else:
            count[2] += 1       # (B)
    return count
```

Is the closest working version of your code.

You might also explore and consider the `collections.namedtuple` class or `dataclass` module for your return value, instead of a "raw" 3-element list.